# PHP file upload/download security

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, upload, download

I'm just wanting to confirm that what I'm doing is actually secure.

Firstly, I have a GoDaddy shared hosting account, but I do have a dedicated IP address.

Let's call my server path `/path`.
My site's files are located in `/path/mysite`
When a user uploads a file, I move it to `/path/uploads/file_name`.
It is impossible for someone to reach that folder via a URL.
To add, I have a .htaccess file in `/path/uploads` with the following:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.1.1.1 #let's say 1.1.1.1 is my server's IP address.
```

And then to actually initiate a download of the file, my users will follow a link to `mysite.com/file.php?q=[file_id]`

And in `file.php`, I download like so:

```
$mime = mime_content_type($location);
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
header('Content-type: '.$mime);
readfile($location);
```

As far as I know, it's not possible for anyone's uploaded files to run on my server, but I may be wrong.

Are there any security gaps that I need to take care of?

Comment: If your document root is `/path/mysite` and your uploads folder is `/path/uploads` then its not accessible by url, php tho can always get to the files so only `deny from all` is required. Also check for uploads called `.htaccess`

Comment: There are a few more declarations you can probably add to the .htaccess like `Options -ExecCGI` that may help depending what kind of files you're expecting to be uploading and downloading. It might help to expand your question and say what kind of files you think it's reasonable for a user to upload and download so we have a better idea what sorts of files could easily be guarded against.

Comment: In addition, again depending what you're doing, it might be wise to tweak the permissions on the /path/upload directory.

Comment: This thread may be of help http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=672581 at the way bottom of the page.

Comment: GoDaddy has terrible hosting, its more suer to find a better one

Comment: if `$location` is simply `$_GET['q']`, then users can grab ANY file on your server.

Comment: Regarding my post/link, more specifically #12. I was faced with a similar problem, and that did the trick for me. However, I do have a client on GoDaddy, and certain features were not available in regards to `.htaccess`.

Comment: Sorry, I made an error on the link, here is the one I meant (#3) http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-4093.html

Comment: What I ended up doing was (added your [file_id]): 
`<Files somefile.xxx>` 
`SetEnvIf Referer "^http://www.yoursite\.com/path/to/file/file\.php?q=[file_id]" auth_referral` 
`order deny,allow` 
`deny from all` 
`Allow from env=auth_referral` 
`</Files>` 

Could work

Comment: @MarcB I use the ID to query a DB file to get the actual location.

Comment: @palintropos I am going to treat it like any and all kinds of files will be up and downloaded, so I want to be able to guard against anything. You say that `Options -ExecCGI` may help. Do you know what specifically it would help? And do you have a web link where I could look at other available options/tweaks that might benefit me?

Comment: @Fred What I believe you're suggesting is that I specify for each and every file `<Files ....> .... </Files>` I don't believe this would be necessary because my `.htaccess` has `deny from all`. Not to mention, the directory is not accessible by URL, but only by PHP script. And again, I don't think the referrer portion is necessary because it can't be accessed via URL.

Comment: @Jakar you can read about the Options directive in lots of places, e.g. [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html). ExecCGI controls whether the directory can run cgi scripts (perl, PHP, etc) which is probably not something you want in a download directory, since the potential malicious uses far outweigh the benign (hence the - to turn it off).

Comment: @Jakar to that end you can also specially set the mime type for several types of potentially problematic (script) files like php, pl, etc. to text/plain so the server's default behavior becomes to simply output the source code.

Comment: @palintropos I actually want to avoid having to do anything specific to certain files. To test, I uploaded a `PHP` file with how I already had it configured. I then accessed it via my php script, and it downloaded. No code from the file was run. I did add the `Options -ExecCGI` to my `.htaccess`.

Comment: I borrowed from http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-4093.html (post #3) and came up with the following which works for me 

`<Files protected_file.php>` 
`SetEnvIf Referer "^http://www.yoursite.com/access/access_file_above.php" local_referral` 
`SetEnvIf Referer "^http://www.othersite.com" auth_referral` 
`order deny,allow ` 
`deny from all` 
`Allow from env=local_referral` 
`Allow from env=auth_referral` 
`</Files>`

Comment: @Jakar I think you might still want to look into both AddHandler and AddType carefully to override certain kinds of default behaviors for script files. There are probably values you can assign to make sure they force download instead of executing or running through the parser. I can't tell you what they are off the top of my head, but I can research it later when I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the `allow from 1.1.1.1` as this will allow you to access this directory via Apache services.  No, you will only ever access this directory from an executing program / script.

Second, this is a pretty standard template to address this type of problem.  So its well worth looking and widely used packages such as MediaWiki or BB engines such as phpBB approach this and mirror some of their security checks.

My third suggestion picks up the point made by Marc B, you need to think about constraints on the file name and file types that you want to allow / support, and the possibilities of other attacks.  One approach is simply to store files with the filename and ascending ID and keep the ID/user filename as a map in a DB table.  You also need to think not only about attacks on your server, but that malicious users could use this upload facility to implement [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and other attacks.

Comment: 1. I removed the `allow from`. 2. I will check those out. 3. I want there to be absolutely NO constraints on what can be uploaded. When I store the files, I assign them an ID. I store the ID and filename in a MySQL DB. Then when someone goes to /file/?q=[file_id] I query the DB to find the file name that matches the file's ID. And I don't really see how someone could do an `XSS` attack as the files are not accessible by the user except to download.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the PHP interpreter for that directory completely with

> php_flag engine off

in your .htaccess. This should give you a good degree of protection against stuff running in **that** directory.

However, you didn't show your upload code, so it's hard to tell what you are doing there: you really want to check you are not vulnerable to path traversals as that would completely void your protection here.

The download code, too, might be vulnerable: if you are actually using the snippet you posted, the attacker can download any file on your application by simply using "../../whatever.php" as a filename (again, path traversal). Or use that script as a praxy and more - hence you want to make sure you validate the filename value.

Comment: Sorry but php_flag only works if PHP is running under mod_php.  A Godady shared service doesn't.  But I agree that it is essential to **deny from all** in that directory.

Comment: Better would be as I suggested above to set the mime type in Apache for several known script file types to text/plain so it just echos source code instead of executing for that directly.

Comment: PHP will only execute a set of mime types, I fail to see how setting text/plain helps in any way. TerryE you are right, didn't know godaddy wasn't mod_php (CGI, bad idea)./\